# Get count of rows from MSSQL database with Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to get the number of rows from a Microsoft SQL database table in Powershell as an integer and am stuck peeling the figure out of the object Powershell is returning.

I have;

```
$SQLServer = "MSSQL01"   $SQLDBName = "TheTable" $SqlQuery = "select count(*) from cases where opened_date =< '2014-07-30'"

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Now $DataSet.Tables[0] in this instance returns an object like;

```
Table Name
-----------

45
```

How can I grab just the 45 as an int?

Comment: Look at `ExecuteScalar` instead of filling an adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ExecuteScalar` is a much better solution. If, for some reason, you want to stick with the `DataSet` use either:

```powershell
$DataSet.Tables[0].'Table Name'
```

or

```powershell
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Table Name"
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at `ExecuteScalar`:

```
$SQLServer = "MSSQL01"   
$SQLDBName = "TheTable" 
$SqlQuery = "select count(*) from cases where opened_date =< '2014-07-30'"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.Open() 
$Rows= [Int32]$SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: You should to remove `$DataSet` from the `ExecuteScalar` call. The method doesn't take a parameter and $DataSet isn't initialised in your example.

Comment: Seems like I'm close but I get "ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection.  The connection's current state is closed", your example code above doesn't differ from mine but for the executescalar v filling an adapter, why does the connection now not open?

Comment: Updated. You need to explicitly open yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version which provides two encapsulated functions, based on @jessehouwing's answer. This also handles an optional port, choice of TrustedAuth vs. User/Passwd Authentication, and an optional WHERE clause.

```powershell
function createSqlConnection($sqlServer, $sqlPort, $dbName, $user, $password) {
    $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.sqlConnection
    if ($sqlPort) { $sqlServer = "$sqlServer,$sqlPort" }
    if ($user -and $password) {
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$sqlServer; Database=$dbName; User Id=$user; Password=$password"
    } else {
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$sqlServer; Database=$dbName; Integrated Security=True"
    }

    return $sqlConnection
}

function getRowCount($sqlConnection, $table, $where = "1=1") {
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM $table WHERE $where"
    $sqlConnection.Open()
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sqlQuery, $sqlConnection)
    $row_count = [Int32] $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
    $sqlConnection.Close()
    return $row_count
}
```

To use it:

```powershell
$dbConn = createSqlConnection 'db-server' $null 'myDatabase' $user $password
$count = getRowCount $dbConn 'the_table'
```

Comment: Your optional where clause adds a nice SQL injection vulnerability to the function.